# Mapping the enum to spring form select in a different way

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have the enum set

```
public enum MyEnum {

    A("AND"), //
    I("INTER");
}
```

I have the spring form:select in my jsp page which populates the AND and INTER As I want , but while submitting the form it throws the exception , can't map String AND to enum type Status.

My Controller :

```
model.addAttribute("list",MyEnum.values);
```

**

> But it works when I modify my enum and add one more value like ,
>   OR("ÖR") , now If I select OR from UI , it gets saved properly in the
>   database.But it won't work for A or I.

**

Note : Down voting to this question simply means that you have not read question carefully.I have already searched on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: @PaulVargas: let me confirm the same

Comment: what exception it is?

Comment: @msangel:Can't map AND to MyEnum , but it works when I modify my enum and add one more value like , OR("ÖR") , now If I select OR from UI , it gets saved properly in the database.But it won't work for A or I.

Comment: Are you trying to select A or AND on the UI ?

Comment: Make sure you separate the select option label from the submitted value (the enum constant).

Comment: @joaonlima: I am trying to select AND on UI

Comment: Vive it a try with just A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks all for answering but I found the way , how to deal with this.

```
<form:options items="${mList}" itemLabel="name" />
```

**Use spring form options in following way don't specify the itemValue field , spring will do it for you. :)**

Comment: the `name` property of a ENUM is private, how did you get it? `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'name' of bean class [xxx.users.Role]: Bean property 'name' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`

Answer (score 2):

I suppose when spring converts your enum to select option it uses `toString` method on enum and you overrided it so it returns "AND" for `A` and "INTER" for `I`. When it converts selected option back to enum it probably uses `valueOf` but I'm not sure.
In any case you should try to implemend your own formatter for this field that will convert enum to String and back to enum correctly. Check this article: http://bthurley.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/enum-translations-in-spring-mvc/

Comment: this document does not contain the thing which I want :(